# Does the Captain Enchantment Tier 2 Boots Stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the [Preseason 3 Patch Notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/preseason-3-patch-notes), it says,

> Enchantment - Captain: Allied champions moving towards you gain a
>   movement speed boost. Additionally, nearby allied minions gain a large
>   movement speed bonus.

Is the aura from [Captain Enchantment](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Captain) unique or does it stack?

If every member of the team has this enchantment and moves towards each other, is the movement speed bonus quintupled?

Comment: hard to know before its released

Comment: @Paralytic But it is released ...

Comment: The enchantment is unique, but I'm not sure of the mechanics for multiple people own it/the stacking order.

Comment: @SadlyNot really now? guess i missed a lot in the past 3 days

Comment: @Paralytic Not sure when they released it but you should try it out!

Comment: Damn my internet. Since I moved (being left without dsl for a couple of months now) a million changes have occured. They make a new map, they introduce new items, they even created a new category now? BAD timing is bad....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Passive from Captain boots does not stack; walking toward two allies with Captain-enchanted boots will not provide any bonus greater than if you were walking toward one ally:

Two allied champions both wearing Captain boots walking toward each other will, however, both receive the bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Named Unique Auras do NOT stack. However the [Aura Article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aura) specifically says that the [Captain Enchantment](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Captain) is a passive effect and NOT an Aura.

The following is an example of a traditional "Aura"

Text is copied from [Preseason Item Page](http://competitive.na.leagueoflegends.com/preseason/items) and can be found by expanding the Runic Bulwark item.

> Runic Bulwark Cost: 3200 (650)
>   +400 Health
>   +20 Armor
>   +30 Magic Resist
>
> UNIQUE Aura - Legion: Nearby allies gain 10 Armor, 30 Magic Resist and
>   10 Health Regen per 5.
>
> **(Unique Auras with the same name don't stack.)**

The way Auras work is HAVING the item gives you the bonus and then you can get the AURA bonus from a nearby ally. (Having 2 Runic Bulwark on a team gives both of the **holders** the Aura effect twice but each of their teammates receive only 1 instance of the Aura). Having the Captain Enchantment on your boots and then an ally having Captain on their boots won't give either one of the champions 2 Captain Bonuses since the bonus only applies to allied champions moving toward the holder.

The question boils down to: "If those 2 champions stand next to each other, will a third nearby allied champion get 2 instances of Captain MS buff?" and if the Captain Buff is an AURA the answer is no because you can't get two of the same named AURA from allies.

However, according to the [Aura Article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aura) the [Captain Enchantment](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Captain) is a considered a passive effect and NOT an aura. Therefore, it would seem that a champion could receive a 16% ms buff if two teammates have the Captain Enchantment.

Comment: I have to double check this answer. The Captain "Enchantment" upgrade to Boots is not specifically listed as an "Aura" and apparently doesn't show up as an icon when your champion receives the benefits from the boots.

Comment: It's also good to list that no aura items stack unless two people on the team have the same item. (i.e. Vlad and Ahri both have WOTA. They both will get one aura bonus from their item and another aura from their teammate. Everyone else on the team however, would only receive the bonus from one aura. Probably the closest of them or whichever they came into contact with first I would imagine.)

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Your WOTA example, while a great example of team synergy, is not an example of aura stacking. WOTA gives others the buff, not yourself. If only Ahri had the WOTA she would not receive its aura benefits. This is why getting two on a team is a viable strategy, unlike getting two of most other aura items.

Comment: @AdamP I know for a fast that is how it works. Why would it make any sense to build WOTA if you lose the spellvamp on it? Also, the LoL [wiki page on WOTA](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_Ancients) agrees with me. It's too long to copy/paste here but it's in the notes section.

Comment: AdamP, can you quote a source?  AFAIK, VanBuskirk correctly described how stacking WOTAs works.

Comment: -1, incorrect. Unique Auras that apply to their owner can stack up to one other time if a teammate applies that same aura to the owner (such as Aegis of the Legion and Will of the Ancients). The reason Captain Enchantment will not stack is because it does not apply to its owner.

Comment: It appears that the Captain Enchantment is not an Aura. I have updated my answer to include links to the Aura article and the Commander Enchantment article.

Comment: Still not certain that answer is correct. This needs to be tested.

Comment: @AdamP WotA definitely provides the bonus to both yourself and teammates. You **are** an allied champion. The trick is in the wording of the captain enchantment - although you are an allied champion, it is impossible to move towards yourself, thus you don't get the bonus.